# Type Error can only concatenate list (not generator ) to list

Tags: python

```
def preorder(self, root): 

        """
        :type root: Node
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        if(root==None):
            return []
        if(len(root.children)==0):
            return [root.val]
        ans=[root.val]
        # for i in root.children:
        #     ans.extend(self.preorder(i))
        # return ans
        return ans+(self.preorder(i) for i in root.children)
```

So in this code an error is given that a generator can't be concatenated to a list. But after recursion  self.preorder(i) for I in root.children will return a list itself for every child. So why is the error coming pls help?

Comment: Please edit your code to be a [mre] so I can paste it into a file and run it _without adding anything_ - if your current code is much larger then cut out everything irrelevant - a [mre] has just enough code (and data, if needed) to show the error you are asking for help with. Also please edit the full error traceback into your question.

Comment: You need to be more clear of what it's happening and what it's supposed to happen...

Answer (score 0):

`(self.preorder(i) for i in root.children)` is a generator expression. If you want to return a full list of values immediately, you want a list comprehension instead.

```
return ans + [value for i in root.children for value in self.preorder(i)]
```

If you want `preorder` itself to return a generator, you can write

```
def preorder(self, root):
    if root is None:
        return
    yield root.val
    for c in root.children:
        yield from self.preorder(c)
```